# Tuple 3 on implicit toJson function not compiling in Scala / Playframework

Tags: scala, playframework

Tuple-2 works when I do an implicit JSON call in the Playframework:

```
def toJson(itemTuple: List[((Item, ItemOption), List[Picture])]) : JsObject = { ... }
```

I defined an implicit Writes method and all is fine. In this case I can pass a list like so within an "outer" JSON block:

```
"items" -> Json.toJson(itemTupleList)
```

and it the implicit method "toJson" is executed on each element. However when I extend it to a Tuple-3 it fails:

```
def toJson(itemTuple: List[((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])]) : JsObject = { ... }
```

This yields:

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[No Json deserializer found for type List[(models.butik.Item, models.butik.ItemOption, models.butik.ItemAttribute)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.]
```

I thought I did:

```
implicit val iW = new Writes[((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])] { ... }
```

What is the reason for this? Is there another way to achieve the same without the implicit method (I am a bit new to Scala).

(BTW: The reason to split up the Item data into three containers is due to the 22 tuple elements of Scala that Slick relies on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Scratch {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(toJson(List(((1, 2, 3), List(3)))))
  }

  def toJson(itemTuple: List[((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])]) : JsValue =
    Json.toJson(itemTuple)

  implicit val iW: Writes[((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])] = new Writes[((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])] {
    def writes(x: ((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])) = Json.parse("[1, 2, 3, [3]]") // TODO
  }

  type Item = Int
  type ItemOption = Int
  type ItemAttribute = Int
  type Picture = Int
}
```

.

```
% cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.0-RC2"
)

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

% sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jason/code/scratch4/project
[info] Set current project to scratch4 (in build file:/Users/jason/code/scratch4/)
[info] Running scratch.Scratch
[[1,2,3,[3]]]
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Sep 26, 2013 1:16:21 PM
```

Make sure to annotate the return type of your implicits, rather than using an inferred type. If the implicit appears *below* the place you need it and the return type is not explicit, the compiler will not consider it. If it did, type inference could run into nasty cycles.

BTW, you can clean up the code a little with a type alias:

```
 def toJson(itemTuple: List[Record]): JsValue =
    Json.toJson(itemTuple)

  implicit def recordWrite: Writes[Record] = new Writes[Record] {
    def writes(rec: Record) = {
      Json.parse("{}") // TODO
    }
  }

  type Record = ((Item, ItemOption, ItemAttribute), List[Picture])
  type Item = Int
  type ItemOption = Int
  type ItemAttribute = Int
  type Picture = Int
}
```